# Reverse direction for multiple has_one relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to model the following scenario? I need to access the bicycle from within the wheel at validation time, so I can't just omit the `has_one`.

```
class Bicycle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :front_wheel, :class_name => 'Wheel'
  belongs_to :back_wheel, :class_name => 'Wheel'
end

class Wheel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bicycle
end

b = Bicycle.new
b.front_wheel = Wheel.new
b.back_wheel = Wheel.new

b.save

# Fails with
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `wheel_id'
```

The DB schema:

```
create_table "bicycles", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "front_wheel_id"
  t.integer  "back_wheel_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "wheels", force: true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

If anyone finds a better title for this question, please update it or drop me a line.

Comment: What's your db schema?

Comment: Can you show bicycles and wheels tables schema?

Comment: Just added the DB schema.

Comment: I tried what you did. It's working all well for me, are you sure you've not missed anything?

Comment: Only thing is the `has_one :bicycle` association which you will have to change with `has_one :bicycle, primary_key: 'front_wheel_id'` or with these 2: `has_one :front_wheel_bicycle, foreign_key: 'front_wheel_id', class_name: 'Bicycle'` and `has_one :back_wheel_bicycle, foreign_key: 'back_wheel_id', class_name: 'Bicycle'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `has_one` will be looking for `wheel_id` on the table.  But you'll have `front_wheel_id` and `back_wheel_id` and the wheel doesn't know if it's the front wheel or back wheel.  I don't know if you can set two possible options for foreign key.  I would assume not.  Which means your structure will need a rethink.

You could use single table inheritance as I assume front and back wheels will be identical.  So you'd have a wheels model and the wheels database would have a type column with a front and back wheel model inheriting from it.

```
class Wheel < ActiveRecord::Base    
end

class FrontWheel < Wheel
  has_one :bicycle
end

class BackWheel < Wheel
  has_one :bicycle
end
```

Then you'd have

```
b = Bicycle.new
b.front_wheel = FrontWheel.new
b.back_wheel = BackWheel.new

b.save
```

Then because of the model names the front wheel should successfully look for `front_wheel_id` and back wheel will look for `back_wheel_id`